# How to get all subset from a set composed by couples and singles

Tags: python, list, dynamic

I have to implement an algorithm in python with these features:
Let there be a set of n elements, and suppose that each element can be paired with some other element or can be unpaired ("single"). Each element can be paired only once. An algorithm is implemented to find out the total number of ways in which the n elements can remain single or can be paired.
For example: Input : n = 3 Output : 4
Explanation:{1}, {2}, {3} : all elements are single{1}, {2, 3} : 2 and 3 are paired but 1 is single. {1, 2}, {3} : 1 and 2 are paired but 3 is single. {1, 3}, {2} : 1 and 3 are paired, but 2 is single.
The pairs {a, b} and {b, a} are considered as one pair.

I tried to approach the problem with dynamic programming, but i have no idea how to reduce problem to a base case and for this reason i am blocked.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem. I'm sure you can figure out the formula with math alone, but it is probably easier to do it with code. One way to do it would be to create a set of all the unique subsets and then combine those subsets to form valid supersets.

What? (I hear you say)

So start by adding each member to a list:

```
subsets = [[1],[2],[3]]
```

Then write a function that combines these members into pairs of two, and add that to your list of subsets:

```
pairedSubsets = [[1,2],[2,3],[1,3]]
subsets = [[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[2,3],[1,3]]
```

Then you'll need a function that merges the subsets together to form valid supersets. The basic algorithm would be:

1. Pick the first subset (say you pick `[2,3]`)
2. Filter out all other subsets that have shared members with the selected subset (filter out `[2]`,`[3]`,`[1,3]`,`[1,2]`)
3. Pair up with the remainders (in this case only `[1]` remains as an option).

If you had picked `[1]`, we start by eliminating `[1,2]` and `[1,3]` then we can pair up with the rest (this case is not as straightforward, but still quite doable).

After that you may have to filter for duplicates, then you'll have your sets:

```
supsersets = [[[1],[2],[3]],[[1,2],[3]], ... ]
```

This method is almost certainly not ideal, but you have to start somewhere.